# Android: JSONException when loading data from Rails API

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I have an issue parsing JSON response from Rails API in Android app.
I have rather standart json parser in my Android app. It seems to work great when I feed it with some JSON urls from tutorials (like this one: http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php.
But as soon as I put there my link (I use tunnel to my localhost) - it fails to parse any data and gives

```
JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

So I believe that problem is in my servers response. In browser response looks like

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "title": "Sometitle",
        "address": "Someaddress"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sometitle2",
        "address": "Someaddress2"
    }
]
}
```

and json validators show it is valid. I researched similar problems and didn't found a solution, I do not know what can be the reason. Could anyone suggest solution?

UPD. My actual Android code:

```
public class JsonParser {

final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // make HTTP request
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

}

and then in my Activity:

```
          JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

          // get json string from url
          JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(ITEMS_URL);

          // get the array of items
          dataJsonArr = new JSONArray(json);
```

Comment: You need to post the code of where you try to parse the JSON in your app.

Comment: **"In browser response looks like..."** : Is that the browser on your Android device or on your desktop?

Comment: @Ascorbin updated with Parser code

Comment: @Vla : In that case, look at it in your desktop browser again then view the source - there may be other stuff in there (e.g., HTML tags etc).

Comment: @Squonk Actually it seems to be html-styled in browser, but why then online json-validators show that json from url is valid?
Another issue is that i have some strings there in Cyrylic letter, could be it the reason? I am not sure.

Comment: @Vla : Do you mean you're actually passing the URL into an on=line validator or copy pasting what you see in the browser window? If it's the first, the validator must be detecting the HTML and stripping it out leaving just the valid JSON string before parsing / validating it. One thing I noticed in your JSONParser is creating an `InputStreamReader` using `iso-8859-1` encoding. Are you sure that is correct? Have you tried `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: @Squonk Yes, this is reasonable and I tried this as well, but encoding was not the solution. **railsdog** made correct suggestion about 'HttpGet' - this worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual issue was using an HttpPost for the request, which should be a HttpGet.

The response from the API is likely an error response due to the request mapping on the server side.

Comment: I tried this, but situation is still the same - I get error with my API url and get no error with one from tutorial. This should be Url problem I believe

Comment: What is the response from the API if you use curl? And are you using the right method in your Android code?  GET or POST? Just wondering. You might be using Postman in the browser to do a POST, but that isn't apparent.

Comment: This is simple GET request.
What about curl - it occured to be strange:
`{"items":[{"title":"\u0421\u0432\u0456\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043e\u043a","address":"\u0443\u0440. \u0413\u0440\u044f\u0434\u0430"},{......`
Cyrylic stuff seems to be encoded. could this cause the problem?

Comment: Then I think you want an HttpGet, not         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

The wrong HttpMethod is being received by the API, and you're likely receiving an error message in the device code.

Comment: Ok, thats not Cyrilic issue - I changed API code to send me dumy English data - problem is still there.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thank You much for the suggestion!
Please update Your answer so I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a server side issue, In your method from where you are hitting server for response you must be getting response in a String variable first, try to get response from there, may be you got response correct from there..